# how to apply shopping cart price rule for registered member to a guest users cart

Tags: magento, discount, magento-rules

- Price rule is defined for both specialgroup and guest lets say 3% on 10 or more products.
- pricing for product A for specialgroup is 10 and for guest is 12 (tier pricing)
- Special checkout rules based on product quantity and specialgroup/guest (my custom ship module)
- Added a special product(virtual product added) which when added to cart makes guest register for specialgroup
- problem is i dont want to do checkout twice once for buying that special product and then the products that i need to buy with discounted price.
- tried to find a way to activate these rules setup for specialgroup for guest if they are adding that  special product to buy membership.
- i hope its clear now.

---

As I mentioned its Group Price that are set at backend and those are not percentage based. So if some one is currently guest but will become member after purchasing membership we want lowered cart price for each item. I solved this by adding cart update and add observers. In these observers I edited the base price of each item in the cart. SO I check if that membership product is in cart and apply membership price of each product. The shopping cart rule now works on lowered price in the cart and holds well. So both rule work.

Comment: Can you more clearly define the *condition* on which the rule should be applied to the guest cart?  And you say "product is active" - but aren't all products in the cart active, by definition? Or do you mean something other than "active"?

Comment: i have updated it. i am thinking of making a small extension to apply these rules to guest cart when that membership purchase product is added. have better ideas?

Comment: Why not just create a second rule for the guest?

Comment: because guest will get discount on its base price and not members base price which is less.

Comment: So what do you want? Make the rule dependent on whether they are a guest or member.  If you want the guest to get a smaller discount, then set up a guest rule and apply a smaller discount percentage.  If you want the guest to get member pricing, then set up a guest rule and apply a larger discount.  This is completely solveable with the addition of a new rule.

Comment: if user dont want to register and just wants to checkout gets higher price per product and discount % on cart total. but when it tries to register and wants to checkout the cart in the same go I want to give it discount. its like if guest checks out group membership product and some other stuff from site it is treated as group member.